# Convertir lista a tupla en PYTHON

Tags: python

Estoy intentando convertir una lista a tupla, solo que no entiendo bien el concepto o me falta algo basico... tengo esto:

```
lista=[]

for x in range(5):

    valor=int(input("Ingrese valor:"))

    lista.append(valor)

mayor=lista[0]

for x in range(1,5):

    if lista[x]>mayor:

        mayor=lista[x]

menor=lista[0]

for x in range(1,5):

    if lista[x]<menor:

        menor=lista[x]


print("****LISTA****")

print(lista)

print("El mayor de la lista es: ")

print(mayor)

print("El menor de la lista es: ")

print(menor)

lista=list(tuple)

print(lista)
```

Comment: Analicemos-> `lista = list(tuple)`.. qué es `tuple`? Y qué es `list`? Son los constructores de tuplas y listas, no objetos tuyos! Estás haciendo una lista con un método vacío (`tuple` pide parámetros que es lo que meterá en la tupla!). Prueba a hacer `lista = tuple(lista)` y verás :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido Emmanuel! c:
La función incluida en Python `tuple`, convierte cualquier iterable (incluyendo listas), en tuplas. Acepta como primer argumento el iterable que deseas transformar.
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de una lista que se convierte en tupla:

```
print(tuple([1,2,3]))
```

Que imprime en la consola

```
(1,2,3)
```

Que es como se representan las tuplas en Python.

---

Por otro lado, la función que usaste, `list`, es igual a `tuple`, solo que convierte el iterable a lista.

```
print(list("123"))
```

Imprime en la consola:

```
["1","2","3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python tiene un segundo tipo de lista, llamado tuples. A diferencia de las listas, estos son inmutables Se escriben utilizando paréntesis en lugar de paréntesis cuadrados:

(1, 2, 3) en lugar de [1, 2, 3]

```
listTotuple = tuple(lista)
print("Lista convertida a tuple \n",listTotuple)
```